# Using Weka extension packages in Java

Tags: java, weka

I am able to integerate Weka in my Java project via Maven by putting this in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
    <artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

But I need to use some extension packages of Weka which is not already available in Weka. How can I use Weka extension packages (Not just Weka core) in my Java project?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you add those extensions pakages as dependencies if available?